# A Characterization of Lebesgue measurable Sets by G-delta and F-sigma sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-measures

Folland provides a proof for the following proposition:

> If $E \subset \mathbb{R}$, the following are equivalent:
>
> 1. $E$ is Lebesgue Measurable (in the domain Lebesgue measure)
> 2. $E = V - N_1$ where $V$ is a $G_{\delta}$ set and $N_1$ has measure zero.
> 3. $E = H - N_2$ where $H$ is a $F_{\sigma}$ set and $N_2$ has measure zero.

He provides the following proof:
To show the first implies the second and third, we being by noting that we can choose a compact $K_j \subset E$ and open $U_j \supset E$ such that $$\mu(U_j) - \frac{1}{2^j} \leq \mu(E) \leq \mu(K_j) + \frac{1}{2^j}$$
If we define $V = \bigcap_1^{\infty}U_j$ and $H = \bigcup_1^{\infty}K_j$, then $H \subset E \subset V$ and the measures of $H$,$E$, and $V$ are all equal.

My question: I can see how the inequality arises, then taking limit on the upper and lower bounds, together with the using the upper and lower continuity on measures I can see that $$\mu(V) \leq \mu(E) \leq \mu(H)$$ But by monotonicty this means: $$V \subset E \subset H$$
All my inclusions are going the wrong way! How is Folland concluding that $H \subset E \subset V$?

Comment: There are Borel sets in your title, but not your question!

Comment: ya, i just realized that, I'm looking at the question statement now

Comment: How do you get from $\mu(V)\le\mu(E)$ to $V\subseteq E$?

Comment: isn't that monotonicity?

Comment: Monotonicity is $V\subseteq E\implies\mu(V)\le\mu(E)$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown paraquote: "The significance of Prop 1.19 (the proposition I quote) is that all Borel sets (or more generally all sets in the domain of lebesgue measure) are reasonably simple modulo sets of measure 0". My notes said Borel, but I guess its true for its completion too. Hence the ambiguity.

Comment: Again, your theorem is a characterisation of Lebesgue-measurable sets, **not** of Borel sets.

Comment: Oh, okay, so he's talking about Lebesgue sets, then making a corollary statement about Borels?

Comment: Your question gives no clue about that, but let me speculate: is it because all Borel sets are Lebesgue measurable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, $\mu(V) \leq \mu(E) \leq \mu(H)$ definitely does *not* imply $V \subset E \subset H$.  Monotonicity of the measure gives the converse of this implication, not this implication.  For instance, $\mu([0,1])<\mu([2,4])$ but $[0,1]\not\subset[2,4]$.

As for where the inclusions $H \subseteq E \subseteq V$ come from, this is just immediate from the definitions of $H$ and $V$.  By definition, $H$ is a union of sets $K_j$ which are all contained in $E$, so $H$ is also contained in $E$.  Similarly, $V$ is an intersection of sets $U_j$ which all contain $E$, so $V$ also contains $E$.

Comment: oh I see what's happening now, Folland is showing inequality of *measure* in both directions. thanks!